# Parent logic app not waiting for child logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Parent logic app didn't wait for the child logic app to complete and gets completed.

I am using splitOn in child logic app.

Can't find any solution to it.

Comment: Cause in the parent logic it calls the child logic app it's just like a HTTP call and your child logic app returns 200 always even it's not finished or get error.

Comment: I tried this thing :
Parent logic app calls the child logic app and this part is in scope.
If child logic app will send say 404, Parent logic app fails.
It's working as expected, but my problem is not this.
I need child logic app to give response as 200 only when it passes a condition otherwise give 409 or other status. But when i am using "splitOn" in child logic app it is not allowing me to use Action : "Response" and it is automatically sending 200. Using scope becomes pointless when child will give 200 always.

Comment: any update on this issue, could you set it now?

Comment: No, it's not possible for now. Thanks for the help and time :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a scope to run specific actions and a condition to check the scope's status. If any actions in the scope fail or end unexpectedly, the scope is marked "Failed" or "Aborted" respectively.
Under the scope, add a condition that checks the scope's status. 
For more information, follow the **[doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-run-steps-group-scopes)**

Comment: I know the logic behind scope but the problem is not with the scope, it is with the SplitOn, But thanks for trying. I am no longer working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a expected result, in the official doc there is a note about `splitOn`:

> You can't use SplitOn with a synchronous response pattern. Any workflow that uses SplitOn and includes a response action runs asynchronously and immediately sends a 202 ACCEPTED response.

So the child logic app won't return the runs output and it could not be implemented for now, cause it's not just only one run output.

And maybe you could try to list the logic app runs history using the [REST api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflowruns/list) with specific ClientTrackingId. However this output is still not the finished status, some status could be running while some is Succeeded.

Comment: I was working on a POC (Proof of concept) but as i am not able to do the aggregation, i didn't continued it. We had to drop it and i am no longer working on it.